# How do I get my p value from my F test in Stata

Tags: regression, anova, econometrics, stata

. regress healthandpersonal income unemployment barsandres electronics housesales

```
  Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     300
```

-------------+------------------------------           F(  5,   294) =16580.50
       Model |  1.1499e+10     5  2.2998e+09           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  40778600.2   294  138702.722           R-squared     =  0.9965
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.9964
       Total |  1.1540e+10   299  38593905.2           Root MSE      =  372.43

---

healthandp~l |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      income |    3.75344   .2821089    13.30   0.000     3.198231    4.308649
unemployment |   522.3187   20.66876    25.27   0.000     481.6413    562.9962
  barsandres |   .4372481   .0049137    88.99   0.000     .4275777    .4469186
 electronics |   .6193021   .0318181    19.46   0.000     .5566821    .6819222
housesalesno |    3.26532    1.43424     2.28   0.024     .4426405    6.087999

### _cons |  -14530.74   618.6706   -23.49   0.000    -15748.32   -13313.16

Comment: Look at the line `Prob > F.`

Comment: F = 16580.5 , Prob > F = 0.  16580.5 > 0 --> does this mean i reject or fail to reject null hypothesis that .... ????

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests.  The Stata documentation is really great, by the way: it's worth reading.